# Как увеличить громкость видео больше чем на 100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Замысел в том чтобы для видео на Youtube делать до 200% громкости с помощью input type="range". Я понимаю что если сделать `volume = 2;` то будет ошибка. Может есть способ увеличить не громкость видео, а громкость браузера, Web Audio API или тому подобного?

```js
document.querySelector('.volume_control_slider').addEventListener('input', function(){
    if(document.querySelector('video') !== null){
        document.querySelector('video').volume = this.value;
    }
})
```

```html
<input type="range" value="1" min="0" max="2" step="0.02" class="volume_control_slider">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На основе ответа @EzioMercer.. Range max здесь выставлен на 50.. Не знаю с чем это связано, у меня в сниппете видео не воспроизводится, или раз из 10-20 запусков после обновления страницы. Если нажать `править` затем `редактировать пример кода` тогда всё работает..

Не работало из-за `cors policy`

> Ключевой момент: если AudioContext создается до того, как документ
> получит жест пользователя, он будет создан в состоянии
> «приостановлено»

По клику на кнопку `Play` документ получит жест пользователя.

```js
const init = () => {

  let video = document.querySelector('video');

  video.setAttribute('controls', "");
  video.currentTime = 100;
  video.play();
  document.querySelector('.volume_control_slider').addEventListener('input', updatePage)

  const audioCtx = new AudioContext();

  const source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(video);

  const gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

  function updatePage() {
    gainNode.gain.value = this.value;
    document.querySelector('#outVolume').innerHTML = "volume: " + this.value;
  }

  source.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
#control {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
#outVolume {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px black;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="control">
  <input type="range" value="1" min="0" max="50" step="0.02" class="volume_control_slider">
  <div id="outVolume">volume: 1</div>
  <input type="button" value="Play" onclick="init()">
</div>

<video width="280" height="180" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <source  src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4">
</video>
```

Как увеличить громкость в youtube, можно создать сниппет.. Открыть DevTools `ctrl+shift+J` или `f12` перейти во вкладку `Sources` найти в левой колонке `Snippets` создать новый `+ New snippet` вставить код приведенный ниже, сохранить `ctrl+s` и запустить `ctrl + Enter` или нажав `▶` находится внизу.. Код вставляет в нижний левый угол "ползунок", которым можно регулировать громкость в видео. Закрыть DevTools youtube тормозит когда открыты инструменты разработчика.

```js
(function(){
  let video = document.querySelector('video');
  let input = document.createElement('input');

  input.setAttribute('type', 'range');
  input.setAttribute('value', '1');
  input.setAttribute('max', '50');
  input.setAttribute('step', '0.02');

  input.style.position = 'absolute';
  input.style.bottom = '0';
  input.style.left = '20px';

  input.addEventListener('input', function () {
    gainNode.gain.value = this.value;        
  });

  document.body.append(input)

  const audioCtx = new AudioContext();

  const source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(video);

  const gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();    

  source.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Перевод ответа с английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43794379/13349770)

Громкость видео — это процент от 0 до 1, он не может превышать 100%

Единственный способ, которым вы потенциально могли бы это сделать — это направить звук из видеоплеера в API веб-аудио и усилить его там

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource

```
// создайте аудиоконтекст и подключите элемент видео в качестве источника
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(myVideoElement);

// создать узел усиления
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = 2; // удвоить громкость
source.connect(gainNode);

// подключить узел усиления к выходному
gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

Вы можете взять этот звуковой контекст из видео и запустить его через узел усиления, чтобы увеличить громкость звука или применить звуковые эффекты, такие как реверберация. Будьте осторожны, чтобы не увеличить усиление на узле усиления слишком сильно, иначе звук, который уже был обработан, начнет клиппироваться

Наконец, вам нужно подключить узел усиления к аудиоприемнику, чтобы он мог выводить новый звук

Comment: Ок, а что мне нужно сделать чтобы этот код начал работать? Объявить `var myVideoElement = document.querySelector("video");`, потом добавить код, потом для `input type="range"` сдалать `max="2"`. Но после этого `document.querySelector('video').volume = 2;` все равно выдает ошибку. Замысел в том чтобы делать 200% громкости с помощью `input type="range"`. Или я не правильно делаю?

Comment: @Юра Честно сказать не работал никогда с этим АПИ, просто решил поделиться находкой, т.к. это помогло очень многим людям